# Can you not edit the HTML and PHP of your WordPress without paying?

Tags: php, html, code, html-editor

Sorry for the noob question. I'm new to WP.

I'm not seeing where I can edit the HTML and PHP of my blog. I see a bunch of GUI options to change colors, etc. but nothing to change my blog's source code. And am missing something?

I paid $12 to have a custom url, but do I need to pay more to edit my blog's source code? If so, this seems weird considering Tumblr offers both those features (custom url, source code editing) for free.

Comment: Appearence->Editor or browser your site files though FTP or your hosting control panel.

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta. I don't appear to have "Editor" functionality: http://i.imgur.com/grskSpK.png. Wordpress is hosting our blog and I'm not seeng "hosting control panel" either.

Comment: That is really strange. The editor is a core functionality of WordPress. Maybe the theme or a plugin is modified it. Try to use a default theme and deactivate all plugins to see whay of them are removing the editor menu.

Comment: Are you hosting this website on `wordpress.com`? and paid to have custom domain?

Comment: @Roberthue Yes to both questions. Is that wrong?

Comment: @timpeterson then you can not edit theme files. `wordpress.com` does not offer theme customization. You will have to self host your WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the `wp-admin` `dashboard`, then, the editor will be inside `Appearance > Editor`.

The $12 you are paying looks like just the domain name fee. For safely editing the php files, you need ftp or sftp access. You need to contact the Tumblr support team for this issue.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `Appearance > Editor`. See this photo: http://i.imgur.com/grskSpK.png.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the edit capability provided to by the super admin or your hosting provider. It's better if you address this issue to the support team there.